# How to let an image extend while controlling its width and giving it a border-radius in Flutter

Tags: image, flutter, widget

I am working in Flutter where I have a `ListView` in which I show a lot of images, I need those images to have the same width but they can extend as per their original height, i.e. I want a constraint on the width of the image but not the height. It should look like the image below:

[image]

Whereas the code I have written now forces every image to have the same height. Here is the code:

```
                               Container(
                                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .9,
                                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .6,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35),
                                      image: DecorationImage(
                                          image: NetworkImage(memes[index].link),
                                        fit: BoxFit.fill
                                      )
                                  ),
                                ),
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Without `height` the widgets wont come into view, I suggest calculating the image height width, then building the widget according to that height from the image data would work for your problem.
You can use this function to get the image size

```
  Future<Size> _calculateImageDimension(link) {
    Completer<Size> completer = Completer();
    Image image = Image.network(link);
    image.image.resolve(ImageConfiguration()).addListener(
      ImageStreamListener(
            (ImageInfo image, bool synchronousCall) {
          var myImage = image.image;
          Size size = Size(myImage.width.toDouble(), myImage.height.toDouble());
          completer.complete(size);
        },
      ),
    );
    return completer.future;
  }
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: okay but how can I use this along with MediaQuery, I cannot use it without that

Comment: I don't see why you need to use mediaQuery height .
You have your screen height from ```MediaQuery``` then you have another height from the ```_calculateImageDimension``` u need to calculate a percentage from these two and use it.

Comment: I am sorry how can I do that?

Comment: ```
Container(
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .9,
 height: <--Just use the height you get from the function here-->,
 decoration: BoxDecoration(
   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35),
   image: DecorationImage(
     image: NetworkImage(memes[index].link),
     fit: BoxFit.fill
    )
  ),
 )
```

Comment: yeah I tried that, it doesn't work, the image is too stretched